# How to avoid the subquery for this query (SQL Server 2005)?

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is my SQL query:

```
Select 
    FirstName, 
    MiddleName,
    LastName, 
    MatchType, 
    RunsScored
From 
    (Select  
         s.Id, 
         a.FirstName, 
         a.MiddleName,
         a.LastName, 
         s.MatchType, 
         s.RunsScored, 
         Row_Number() Over(Partition By MatchType Order By RunsScored Desc) rn
     From 
         PlayersCareerBatting s 
     Join 
         PlayersBioDataNew a On s.Id = a.Id) x
Where 
    rn = 1
```

I want to speed up this query. I'm going to avoid the sub-query for that. Please help me how to avoid sub-query to run query faster.

[image: this is the output of that query.]

Comment: Hi marc_s, what you have done here? I didn't understand.

Comment: He edited your query. What's the problem with the sub-query? We need to see the execution plan. You can do this with an inner join and a cte, but that's isn't going to improve performance guaranteed.